# How to tell if facebook and gmail firebase user is already created

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication

When the user logs in with Gmail or Facebook, they are taken to a page to input more information about their account (since Gmail or Facebook alone does not provide the information about the user that is needed) and after the user inputs this information, the user is logged in with that provider into firebase, and their information is saved into the firebase real-time database.

My question is, when the user goes back to login again with that account, they are taken to the page to input information that has already been inputted. So how do I find out whether the user has already signed up with Facebook, or Gmail so that I can bypass this screen and go straight to the app?

I was thinking of simply logging in the user with the respected provider as soon as the provider login is complete, then check the userID against one created in the database to see if it exists, and if not, take them to the screen to input data. However, with this approach I am worried that if a user gets to this input data screen, then closes the app and reopens it, the user will be logged in without this information. Is there another way of doing it? thank you!

the way I sign in with facebook:

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("Custom FB Login failed:", err)
            self.popup.showUnsuccessfullAlert(message: "Failed to login with facebook")
            return
        }

        print("the result from logging in = \(result)")

        self.showEmailAddress()
    }
```

and the way I sign in with google:

```
 func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if let err = error {
        print("falied to log into google", err)
        self.popup.showUnsuccessfullAlert(message: "Failed to login with google")
        return
    }else{
        print("successfully logged into google ", user)

        self.gmailUser = user
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSignUpGmail", sender: nil)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method on your AppDelegate.swift file.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
   //check if the user exists here and do something about it.
}
```

This function will execute every time the user opens the app after closing it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the thing is I only want to check if the user exists from that provider after the user presses "login with facebook" etc before actually logging them in with credentials into firebase.

Comment: "I am worried that if a user gets to this input data screen, then closes the app and reopens it, the user will be logged in without this information." – from what you have mentioned, you can check if the user exists inside that function.